# Multiprogress bars in Pycharm's console

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-multiprocessing, tqdm

I've wanted to post this code here so I and others can use it in the future, and it works nicely on vscode. But I would also like it to work properly on PyCharm's Run console, if there is any way to do it.

I'm basically spawning several tasks I want to be run in parallel. For the purpose of the example, the workers just wait a random time for a random number of iterations. In vscode I see some neat progress bars progressing but in Pycharm's console when running or debugging, it prints the bar on a new line each time it is updated, and only by the end prints everything correctly.

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import random
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define n at the start of the file
n = 20

def worker(queue, argument):
    """Function to be executed by each process."""
    description = f"Worker {argument}"

    # Define a random number of operations for this worker
    num_operations = random.randint(10, 100)

    for _ in range(num_operations):
        # Perform some task
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.05, 0.5))  # Random sleep between 50ms and 500ms
        # Send update to the main process along with the total operations count
        queue.put((description, 1, num_operations))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create queue
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Create the processes
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(queue, i)) for i in range(n)]

    # Create progress bars
    progress_bars = {}

    # Define distinct colors for each bar
    colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white', 'black']

    # Start the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    total_updates = 0
    total_operations = 0
    while total_updates < total_operations or total_operations == 0:
        description, increment, total = queue.get()

        if description not in progress_bars:
            # Assign a color to the progress bar
            color = colors[len(progress_bars) % len(colors)]
            # Initialize progress bar if not done yet
            progress_bars[description] = tqdm(total=total, desc=description, bar_format='{desc}: {percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}| {n_fmt}/{total_fmt}', colour=color)
            total_operations += total

        progress_bars[description].update(increment)
        total_updates += increment

    # Join the processes
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    for pb in progress_bars.values():
        pb.close()
```

Is there a setting I can use to solve this? I'm using Pycharm Community Edition on Windows, if it matters.

[image: Bars progressing on vscode]

[image: Weird mess in pyCharm Run console.]

Note: It also runs fine on Pycharms's Terminal, the problem is on the run console.

Comment: It looks the same to me. Please put the output in both.

Comment: @kamyarmg Added images, but to clarify, the problem is in the Run console, not the terminal of PyCharm.